# How can I make 2 elements share the same rollover state in CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser, user-interface

I want a button composed of some text and an icon next to it. I can specify that each has a :hover state in CSS to change its appearance, but how can I arrange my CSS/HTML such that rolling over the text appears to also change the image hover state, and vise versa?

Preferably avoiding JS.

**Update**: *The current state of my fiddling around...*

```
<a class="close"><div class="closebutt"></div></a>

a.close {
    float:right;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #a7dbe6;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a.close:hover  {
    color: #fff;
}
a.vs_rewardClose:before {
    content:"Close "
}
.closebutt {
    background: url(images/close.gif) no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
}
.closebutt:hover {
    background-position: 0px -14px;
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML; help us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your HTML, changing the `background-position` of the `div` is just a matter of:

```
.close:hover > .closebutt {
  background-position: 0px -14px;
}
```

In this way, the `background-position` changes only when its parent gets hovered.

---

This is the original answer I posted before you updated your question:
I usually organize my HTML in this way

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <div class="glyph"></div>
    <div class="text">Button text</div>
</a>
```

**EDIT**: as @Paul D. Waite notes in the comments, this HTML structure is invalid in HTML4 because an `a` can contain only inline elements. So, to fix this we can change the structure in this way, having `span`s as children of the `a`. The CSS remains the same, eventually adding `display: block` if needed.

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span class="glyph"></span>
    <span class="text">Button text</span>
</a>
```

and your CSS in this way:

```
.button {
  /* .. general style */
}

  .button > .glyph {
    /* .. general style for the glyph, like size or display: block */
    background-image: url('..');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
  }

  .button > .text {
    /* .. general style for the text, like font-size or display: block */
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .button:hover > .glyph {
    /* .. change the glyph style when the button is hovered */
    background-position: left bottom;
  }

  .button:hover > .text {
    /* .. change the text style when the button is hovered */
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

In this way you can also change the style adding a new class to the button, in this way:

```
<a href="#" class="button red">
    <div class="glyph"></div>
    <div class="text">Button text</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button gray">
    <div class="glyph"></div>
    <div class="text">Button text</div>
</a>
```

And the CSS

```
.button.red {
  background-color: red;
}

  .button.red > .text {
    color: black;
  }

.button.gray {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

  .button.gray > .text {
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Note that the HTML is invalid in HTML 4, but fine in HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose both in one element and add :hover to this element:

```
.parent:hover > .text { your hover state}
.parent:hover > .icon { your hover state}
```

Comment: If the parent element isn’t a link, then IE6 will need some JavaScript-based help (possibly [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)) to make it work. It is the only way to do it though, and it works in all other browsers.

Comment: I don't have ie6 around to play with it. On top of my head I'd say duplicating the image element and using adjacent sibling selector (+) but I thing ie6 don't support it either. If I had to develop for ie6 (witch I'm very happy not to do:) I'd just skip that one:)

Comment: Oh totally — there isn’t a CSS-only IE 6 solution, and I don’t think there’s anything wrong with leaving this functionality out for IE 6. And in the OP’s HTML, the parent element is a link, so it should work fine in IE 6 anyway.